# Are Unions/Intersections of Cartesian Products of Indexed Sets "Distributive"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

In a situation like $\bigcup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$, could one correctly assume that $\bigcup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times \bigcup\limits_{x \in [0,1]}[0,x^2]$ also holds true? That is to say, is it "distributive" in some sense of the word?

In general, if $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times B_i$ or $\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times B_i$ for some indexed sets $A_i, B_i$, does it hold that:

$$\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times B_i = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} B_i$$
$$\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times B_i = \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \times \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} B_i$$

in general?

Comment: $(0,1) \notin \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$ but $(0,1) \in \bigcup_{x\in [0,1]} [x,1] \times \bigcup_{x\in [0,1]} [0,x^2]$.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because the solution to the first is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and $(0,1)$ is definitely an element of that set.

Comment: If you had $(0, 1) \in \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0, x^2]$ then that would mean $(0, 1) \in [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$ for some $x \in [0,1]$.  But that implies $x \le 0$ since $0 \in [x,1]$ and also $x^2 \ge 1$ since $1 \in [0,x^2]$, giving a contradiction with $x \in [0,1]$.  (In fact, I think $\bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0,x^2] = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x^2 \}$.)

Comment: The union of $[x,1] \times [0,x^2]$ with $x \in [0,1]$ most certainly contains $(0,1)$ since the solution to the union is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, which clearly contains $(0,1)$. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that the first is *not* equal to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ - whereas $\bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [0,x^2]$ is equal to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that that is incorrect and that the first is indeed equal to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. You're making the mistake of thinking that x has to be one value, whereas this is the union of a cartesian product. That is to say, the union is the interval which contains all possible intervals given our x in our index set. The union thus is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, because that cartesian product contains all others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false for unions. To see why, consider the following Battenberg cake (image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Battenbergcake.jpg)), whose cross-section is identified with the subset $[0,1]^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ of the plane:

[image: Battenberg cake]

Let $A_1 = B_1 = [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $A_2 = B_2 = [\frac{1}{2},1]$. Then

- $\bigcup_{i \in \{ 1,2 \}} (A_i \times B_i) = [0,\frac{1}{2}]^2 \cup [\frac{1}{2},1]^2$ consists only of the white squares in the cake; but
- $\left( \bigcup_{i \in \{ 1,2 \}} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{i \in \{1,2\}} B_i \right) = [0,1]^2$ is the entire cake.

---

It is true for intersections. To see why, just chase the definitions. Indeed, $\bigcap_{i \in I} (A_i \times B_i)$ consists of those things which are elements of all the sets $A_i \times B_i$. Now:

- For each $i \in I$, an element of $A_i \times B_i$ is a pair $(a,b)$;
- Such a pair is an element of all the sets $A_i \times B_i$ if and only if $a \in A_i$ for each $i \in I$ and $b \in B_i$ for each $i \in I$;
- But this is equivalent to saying that $(a,b) \in \left( \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcap_{i \in I} B_i \right)$.

Comment: P.S. If anyone knows how to scale the image to make it less obnoxiously huge, please feel free to edit my answer accordingly.